# Struts internationalization

Tags: java, internationalization, struts

I'm working on one portal product. I'm facing problem in making it internationalized. I'm 
using following code

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageHashMap.get(preferredLanguageId));
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale);
session.setAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);
```

for setting the locale.

For one time it is working fine but when I change the langauge again the change the language again, the change is not reflecting in all the pages. Still get the changes made by the last language only. 
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: How is built preferredLanguageId ? And did you try with default Struts (1?) variable: request.getSession().setAttribute(Globals.LOCALE_KEY, locale);

Comment: EmployeeMgmtActionHelper helper = new EmployeeMgmtActionHelper();
Map<Integer, String> languageHashMap = helper.getSupportedLanguageLocaleList();                               so in hashmap i'm getting the locales that are present in my database and i'm retrieving that locales from the map and creating a newer one.

Comment: This is not about "languageHashMap" but "preferredLanguageId".

Comment: consider preferredLangaugeId as key present in the map

Comment: I understand that but how is built preferredLanguageId? session.getAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE) ?

Comment: can you please elaborate a little. I mean what do you mean by built preferredLangaugeId ?

Comment: Can you give the part of the code where the preferredLangaugeId is declared? Can't be more clear... I suppose this is an Integer, how is it valued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the locale is not setting properly.
Try out the following code :

create one map

```
private static Map<Locale, ResourceBundle> messageBundles = new Hashtable<Locale, ResourceBundle>();
```

and then use the following:

```
Locale requestLocale = ActionContext.getContext().getLocale();
ResourceBundle rb = messageBundles.get(requestLocale);
```

and then put that resource bundle in the request scope.

Answer (score 0):

its working fine....

`Locale locale = new Locale(languageHashMap.get(preferredLanguageId));
ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(locale);
session.setAttribute(I18nInterceptor.DEFAULT_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE, locale);`